# ${something} in soap

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, soap

I have the following code:

```
@WebMethod
public String replaceEnvironment(String someVar) {
    return someVar;
}
```

When i'm trying to send a message with string containing `${something}` subsequence, my string is truncated after unmashalling: `${something}` substring is dissappeared. What is the reason of this behaviour? I need to have the same string as i send in `replaceEnvironment` method.

**P.S.** I don't use libs like `Velocity` or `Freemaker` in my project.

SOAP examples.

Request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"     xmlns:ws="http://ws.test.net/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
    <ws:replaceEnvironment>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <arg0>test ${test} test</arg0>
    </ws:replaceEnvironment>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:replaceEnvironmentResponse xmlns:ns2="http://ws.test.net/">
            <return>test  test</return>
        </ns2:replaceEnvironmentResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please write here more information about WSDL.(Rules)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you by any chance making the test call with soapUI?

That gives special meaning to ${xxx} sequences in the request, replacing them with the value of the equivalent soapUI property.

If this is the case, maybe you could use "& # 3 6 ;" (without spaces or quotes) in your request instead of the dollar, and see if soapUI then ignores your sequence and sends it through to your backend code.

HTH

Comment: Oh... This is really soapUI related behavior. I even had no idea to check my WS without soapUI. Thank you!